# How AuthenticationEntryPoint.commence could be used in Spring Boot with WebFlux configured

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I couldn't find a clean usage of it, it's not obvious from the look of it how you can write a response and return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sample usage to return 401 as a json object:

```
    override fun commence(exchange: ServerWebExchange?, ex: AuthenticationException?): Mono<Void> {
        val response: ServerHttpResponse = exchange!!.response
        val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
        objectMapper.registerModule(Configuration.javaTimeModule())
        val result = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(
            Problem(
                exchange = exchange,
                status = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,
                message = ex!!.message
            )
        )
        val resultAsByteArr = result.toByteArray()
        response.statusCode = (HttpStatus.OK)
        response.headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
        return response.writeWith(
            Mono.just(
                response.bufferFactory().allocateBuffer(resultAsByteArr.size).write(resultAsByteArr)
            )
        )
    }
```

---

And this is the corresponding HttpSecurity configuration for Spring Boot 3

`authenticationEntryPoint` calls the `commence` method, I decided to add the method to `GlobalExceptionHandler`, thus it should have  implemented `ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint` interface to have all exception handlers bundled into a single class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
class Configuration {

    @Bean
    fun springWebFilterChain(
        http: ServerHttpSecurity,
        jwtService: JwtService,
        globalExceptionHandler: GlobalExceptionHandler
    ): SecurityWebFilterChain? {
        return http
            .exceptionHandling {
                it
                    //.accessDeniedHandler(globalExceptionHandler)
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(globalExceptionHandler)
            }
            // Disable WebSession creation when using spring-security with spring-webflux
            .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
            .authorizeExchange {
                it.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/auth/login").permitAll()
                    .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/profile/activate").permitAll()
                    .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/profile").permitAll()
                    .anyExchange().authenticated()
            }
            .addFilterAt(JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter(jwtService), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.HTTP_BASIC)
            .httpBasic { it.disable() }
            .logout { it.disable() }
            .formLogin { it.disable() }
            .cors { it.disable() }
            .csrf { it.disable() }
            .build()
    }
}
```

I found this page also very helpful: https://backendstory.com/spring-security-exception-handling/